# Can I change my my.cnf in mysql web hosting? how do it?

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I hired a web hosting, and create a mysql database, I want to configure my.cnf mysql database, how?

Comment: On shared hosting, you likely can't. You'd have to talk to your server administrator.

Comment: You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: Do you have access to the console? Can you access the `my.cnf` file?

Comment: I want to do mysql replication between mysql db on my computer with mysql db in shadred hosting, that's my goal